# Problems with Unity rhythm game if key is pressed and note is not on box then count as miss

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a rhythm game in Unity and so far I've got the basic functionality running. However I would like it so that if the user pressed a key when no arrow is on the box to count as a miss. To do this I added an else statement to `canbepressed`.

This is my code so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NoteObject : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool canBePressed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public KeyCode keyToPress;

    public GameObject hitEffect,goodEffect,perfectEffect,missEffect;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(keyToPress)) {
            if (canBePressed) {
                gameObject.SetActive(false);

                //GameManager.instance.NoteHit();

                if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y) > 0.25)
                {
                    GameManager.instance.NormalHit();
                    Instantiate(hitEffect, hitEffect.transform.position, hitEffect.transform.rotation);
                        
                    Debug.Log("Hit!");
                }
                else if ((Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y) > 0.05f))
                {
                    GameManager.instance.GoodHit();
                    Instantiate(goodEffect, goodEffect.transform.position, goodEffect.transform.rotation);
                    Debug.Log("Good!");

                }
                else {
                    GameManager.instance.PerfectHit();
                    Instantiate(perfectEffect, perfectEffect.transform.position, perfectEffect.transform.rotation);
                    Debug.Log("Perfect!");

                }


            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Miss");
                GameManager.instance.NoteMissed();
                Instantiate(missEffect, transform.position, missEffect.transform.rotation);
            }

        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Activator") {
            canBePressed = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (gameObject.activeSelf)
        {
            if (other.tag == "Activator")
            {
                canBePressed = false;

                GameManager.instance.NoteMissed();
                Instantiate(missEffect, missEffect.transform.position, missEffect.transform.rotation);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem this causes is that when you press a key it says MISS! for the other 3 like this:

[image]

I'm not sure how to change it so that it says miss only for the one that is pressed. I'm guessing that it is because its `getkeydown` for all instead of one. How do I change it to be for each key?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is all of your notes are polling in their update. So when you press a key all notes make this check.

I would suggest you update your ‘canBePressed’ so that it returns false unless its within X distance of the hitbox. This way all the notes above will ignore the key pressed and only notes within X distance to the indicators will do the check.

Answer (score 0):

As wrote in documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

You can use `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)` where `KeyCode.Space` is your button. So you can do something like this:

```
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            // your code to handle user action
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            // your code to handle user action
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            // your code to handle user action
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            // your code to handle user action
        }
```

Or use `if else` statment or even you can try with `switch`. Its up to you.